# Linear charge density, surface charge density and volume charge density

Tags: electrostatics, charge, density

What is the difference among:

1. linear charge density,
2. surface charge density, and
3. volume charge density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as the name suggest. The charge per unit length, area and volume are respectively linear , surface and volume charge densities.